# Receiving commandline input while listening for connections in Python

Tags: python, sockets, client, twisted

I am trying to write a program that has clients connect to it while the server is still able to send commands to all of the clients. I am using the "Twisted" solution. How can I go about this? Here is the code I have so far (I understand that Twisted already uses non-blocking sockets):

```
import threading
print 'threading.'

def dock():
   try:
       from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
       from twisted.internet import reactor
       import currentTime
       print '[*]Imports succesful.'
   except:
       print '[/]Imports failed.'

   #Define the class for the protocol
   class Master(Protocol):
       command = raw_input('> ')
       def connectionMade(self):
           print 'Slave connected.'
           print currentTime.getTime() #Print current time
           #self.transport.write("Hello")

       def connectionLost(self, reason):
           print 'Lost.'
   #Assemble it in a "factory"

   class MasterFactory(Factory):
       protocol = Master


   reactor.listenTCP(8800, MasterFactory())

   #Run it all
   reactor.run()

def commandline():
   raw_input('>')

threading.Thread(target=dock()).start()
threading.Thread(target=commandline()).start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're already using twisted, you should also use it for the console part, instead of using `raw_input` in a thread.

Twisted's event loop can monitor any file descriptor for changes, including the standard input, so you can get event-based callbacks on a new line entered -- It works asynchronously without need for threads.

I've found this [example of a interactive console in a twisted application](http://luoqq.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/song-for-lovers-twisted-interactive.html), maybe you can use it.

Comment: @alex http://luoqq.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/song-for-lovers-twisted-interactive.html

Comment: `.com.br` has unreadable code examples for me. But web archive of [www.oluyede.org/blog/2008/08/31/twisted-interactive-console](http://web.archive.org/web/20091227070520/http://www.oluyede.org/blog/2008/08/31/twisted-interactive-console) works