# Interrupt raw_input in a twisted program

Tags: python, twisted, interrupt, keyboard-events, keyboardinterrupt

I will refer to this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126412/647991) and this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142651/647991):

So what I am doing is:

```
def interrupted(signum, stackframe):
    log.warning('interrupted > Got signal: %s', signum)
    menu.quitMenu = True # to stop my code

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupted) # Handle KeyboardInterrupt
```

The problem is that, while the menu is notified that it must stop, and will do that soon, it can not do it now since it is stucked in a `raw_input`:

```
def askUser(self):
    current_date   = datetime.now().isoformat(' ')
    choice = raw_input('%s > ' % current_date)
    return choice
```

So, since twisted is removing the default interrupt handler, `raw_input` is not stopped. I still need to press `enter` after `^C` for it to stop.

How can I force the raw_input to be stopped, *without* installing the default interrupt handler, which is a source of problems in a twisted context (since twisted itself is not expecting to be interrupted)

I guess the problem is not related to `raw_input` only: any function taking an unbounded time (or longer than a pre-set limit), should be interrupted somehow.

Is there an accepted twisted pattern for this?

### EDIT

This is the full test code:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Menu:

    def __init__(self):
        self.quitMenu = False

    def showMenu(self):
        print '''

A) Do A
B) Do B

'''

    def askUser(self):
        current_date   = datetime.now().isoformat(' ')
        choice = raw_input('%s > Please select option > ' % current_date)
        print
        return choice

    def stopMe(self):
        self.quitMenu = True

    def alive(self):
        return self.quitMenu == False

    def doMenuOnce(self):
        self.showMenu()
        choice = self.askUser()
        if not self.alive() : # Maybe somebody has tried to stop the menu while in askUser
            return
        if   choice == 'A' : print 'A selected'
        elif choice == 'B' : print 'B selected'
        else               : print 'ERR: choice %s not supported' % (choice)

    def forever(self):
        while self.alive():
            self.doMenuOnce()

from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
import signal

class MenuTwisted:

    def __init__(self, menu):
        self.menu = menu
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.interrupted) # Handle KeyboardInterrupt

    def interrupted(self, signum, stackframe):
        print 'Interrupted!'
        self.menu.stopMe()

    def doMenuOnce(self):
        threads.deferToThread(self.menu.doMenuOnce).addCallback(self.forever)

    def forever(self, res=None):
        if self.menu.alive() :
            reactor.callLater(0, self.doMenuOnce)
        else : 
            reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)

    def run(self):
        self.forever()
        reactor.run()
```

Which I can run in two different ways.

*Normal* way:

```
menu = Menu()
menu.forever()
```

Pressing `^C` stops the program immediately:

```
A) Do A
B) Do B


2013-12-03 11:00:26.288846 > Please select option > ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "twisted_keyboard_interrupt.py", line 72, in <module>
    menu.forever()
  File "twisted_keyboard_interrupt.py", line 43, in forever
    self.doMenuOnce()
  File "twisted_keyboard_interrupt.py", line 34, in doMenuOnce
    choice = self.askUser()
  File "twisted_keyboard_interrupt.py", line 22, in askUser
    choice = raw_input('%s > Please select option > ' % current_date)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

As expected.

Twisted way:

```
menu = Menu()
menutw = MenuTwisted(menu)
menutw.run()
```

Pressing `^C` will produce:

```
A) Do A
B) Do B


2013-12-03 11:04:18.678219 > Please select option > ^CInterrupted!
```

But `askUser` is actually not interrupted: I still need to press `enter` for `raw_input` to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to deal with this is to [handle console input asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207669/receiving-commandline-input-while-listening-for-connections-in-python/6207866#6207866), rather than trying to make a blocking input function interruptable.   In other words, `raw_input` is fundamentally the wrong solution to the problem you're attacking.

However, if you really just want to understand what's going on here, the trick is that after calling `reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)`, you have to somehow prompt `raw_input` to exit; it's not going to normally.  However, since you're running it in a thread, it's not actually interruptable at all, because [only the main thread is interruptable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main) in Python.  So I think what you want may actually be impossible.  I believed that perhaps closing `sys.stdin` might pull the rug out from under `raw_input` even if it were in a thread, but it seems that the underlying libraries are doing something more clever than simply reading from the FD, so closing it does no good.